# BASIC got error for "expected end of line"

Tags: error-handling, basic

```
170 FOR J=1 TO 5
180 PRINT
190 NEXT J
200 REM *********************************
210 DIM A(2),B(2),C(2),D(2,100),E(2,100),F(2,100),G$(100)
220 REM *******ENTER INPUT
230 PI=3.141593
```

I got error:
Error on line 210: Expected end of line

What does that mean? How can I fix it?

If I remove line 210, I'll get:
Error on line 230: Expected undefined

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the code you have is intended for a different flavor of BASIC. There are a lot of them and they all have their own subtleties. I'll take a guess: the BASIC you're using doesn't allow dimming multiple arrays in one dim statement. Breaking it up into separate colon-separated statements should fix it:

```
210 DIM A(2): DIM B(2): DIM C(2): DIM D(2,100): DIM E(2,100): DIM F(2,100): DIM G$(100)
```

If that doesn't fix it, or if you prefer, break it into multiple lines. Then the line number in the new error message should narrow down the problematic part:

```
210 DIM A(2)
211 DIM B(2)
212 DIM C(2)
213 DIM D(2,100)
214 DIM E(2,100)
215 DIM F(2,100)
216 DIM G$(100)
```

Comment: thanks so much! I'm new to BASIC, could you advise what tool I can use in Windows to compile my code? I used Quite BASIC but seems wrong. thanks!!

Comment: @user2951298 I don't really know I'm afraid. The last time I used BASIC was in the DOS days. I'm sure there are Windows BASICs or emulators out there though.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is is completely right, but to address your second question, I prefer [GW-Basic](http://www.gw-basic.com), it was simple and gives you an old timey feel.

To use it you'll need either a 32 bit computer, or a DOS emulator like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). If you are unsure how to use doxbox, see [this article](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3338697/how-run-gwbasic-on-64bit-windows-pc/).

To turn off the hotkey strip at the bottom, type in KEY OFF

To save use "save" and to load use "load"

Everything else should be similar to Q-Basic

Comment: Nah, the only BASIC worth it's salt is Dartmouth BASIC running on a Dec PDP-10.  That's *real* BASIC!